# Plugin Emails Being Sent Twice

Tags: plugin-development, emails

I've got an even notifier plugin I have been working on for a specific client project. Sending an email to a single address works fine, but when I loop through a table containing email addresses it is sending duplicate addresses.

I have a global table field (adminEmails) which has two columns, one for a name and the other for an email address.

```
          $adminGlobal = craft()->globals->getSetByHandle('admin');
          foreach($adminGlobal->adminEmails as $key => $admin){
            $email->toEmail = $admin['emailAddress'];
            $body .= "Manager ".$manager->fullName." has submitted an event for approval.\n\n";
            $body .= "Start Date & Time: ".$entry->eventStartDate->format('m/d/Y g:i A'). "\n\n";
            $body .= "House: ".$house->houseName."\n\n";
            $body .= "School: ".$college->collegeName."\n\n";
            $body .= $entry->url;
            $email->body = $body;
            if($email->toEmail != ""){
              craft()->email->sendEmail($email);
            }
          }
```

I have been testing with two email addresses and both addresses receive the same email twice. Not sure what could be causing this. I tried creating a new email model object inside each foreach loop but that didn't help either. Any ideas what's happening here?

EDIT:

If I dump $admin you see the following,

```
array
(
'col1' => 'John Doe'
'col2' => 'some.email@gmail.com'
'adminName' => 'John Doe'
'emailAddress' => 'some.email@gmail.com'
) 0 array
(
'col1' => 'Andrew Clinton'
'col2' => 'some.email@anecka.com'
'adminName' => 'Andrew Clinton'
'emailAddress' => 'some.email@anecka.com'
) 1
```

This is what I was expecting..so why is it sending the same email twice to both addresses?

Comment: If you `Craft::dump($key)` and `Craft::dump($admin)`, what do they look like?

Comment: @BradBell I added the Craft::dump.

Comment: I'd guess that loop is being triggered twice then.  Maybe it's inside an event that's getting fired multiple times?  You can always `Craft::log()` to help verify.